# How to work with rules and actions in sitecore rules

Tags: c#, sitecore

I am trying to add a user to a specific role by using Sitecore rules. I am thinking of writing code in the Items Saved event in /Actions/New User Action item, but I am not sure what to write. Is it even possible to add a user to a role via rules? If so, how can I do so using the type, code, reference, and language fields?

Comment: Try the documentation: http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/rules_engine_cookbook_sc70-a4.pdf

Comment: I already go through this documentation.I didn't found how to write c# code in code field.I am trying to write code in " /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Item Saved/Actions/Sample" item path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create assembly with below code and either call the assembly in your ["event name="item:saved"] handler in app_include or set "Namespace.AddNewUser.AddUser, yourAssembly" in type field.

```
public void AddUser(string domain, string firstName, string lastName, string email, 
        string comment, string telephoneNumber, string jobTitle)
{
    string userName = string.Concat(firstName, lastName);
    userName = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", domain, userName);

    // You can manually set the password or from Sitecore's generator
    string newPassword = Membership.GeneratePassword(10, 3);

    try
    {
        if (!User.Exists(userName))
        {
            Membership.CreateUser(userName, newPassword, email);

            // Edit the profile information
            Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(userName, true);
            Sitecore.Security.UserProfile userProfile = user.Profile;
            userProfile.FullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
            userProfile.Comment = comment;

            // Assigning the user profile template
            userProfile.SetPropertyValue("ProfileItemId", "{this is profileItem's GUID}");

            // Have modified the user template to also contain telephone number and job title.
            userProfile.SetCustomProperty("TelephoneNumber", telephoneNumber);
            userProfile.SetCustomProperty("JobTitle", jobTitle);
            userProfile.Save();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error(string.Format("Error in Client.Project.Security.UserMaintenance (AddUser): Message: {0}; Source:{1}", ex.Message, ex.Source), this);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.how the rule works for this script.

Comment: I think you already defined rules in sitecore, so add the rule condition before executing this method.